# Access spring:form object from custom tag

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

Im trying to write a custom jstl tag for use inside of a  tag, it needs to access a property of the modelAttribute object. So far I can pass the name of the property to my tag handler, but dont know how to then access the modelAttribute. Any help greatly appreciated! NFV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an attribute on the custom tag and set it with the model property using JSP EL.

`<my:customTag modelprop=${modelPropName}/>`

In your custom tag:

```
<%@ attribute name="modelprop" type="com.x.y.MyObj" %>
```